# Is it possible to look up a command that takes no arguments?

Tags: help-system

Is there a way to use `:help` to find commands  that take arguments vs. no arguments?

For example: `:map` (w/o arguments) can list the key mappings for various modes. However, `:help :map` leads me to `:map {lhs} {rhs}` (around line 48) instead of line 114 which explains `:map` w/o arguments.

Currently, I have to type `/:map` then `n` over and over again to find it the section  (around line 114) that contains `:map` w/o arguments.

Comment: Type `:help subject` without pressing enter and then press `<C-d>` (aka Ctrl-D).  It looks like there isn't a direct link for `:map` with no args though.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. I also tried it w/`:set wildcard` and <tab>. I still asked the question in case there was some other way to do it besides the ways described here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Learn_to_use_help

Comment: You can use `/^:map\s<Enter>` which goes right to it.  I see your point; but there just isn't any tag directly on that `help` entry.  So there won't be any way to jump directly to it from the `:help` command.  Improving your regex search is good, though.  E.g., if you know you want something at the start of the line it's good to specify that.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out about `:helpgrep ^:map\s`, but you're way solves it: `:help :map` then `/^:map\s`